# Hyperlink not printing in Vue.js template, but just string works fine

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I print `attrib.link` it works fine,

```
<div v-for="attrib in attributes">
 {{ attrib.link }}
</div>
```

but when I do

```
<div v-for="attrib in attributes">
  <a target='_blank' href={{ attrib.link }} style="color: #880000">{{ attrib.file }}</a>
</div>
```

I am getting error saying "Invalid character error": String contains invalid character.

Comment: Try using `:href=attrib.link` to bind attributes as properties

Comment: try changing it to `_attrib.file` instead of `attrib.file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Vue 2, you could use either

```
<a target='_blank' v-bind:href="attrib.link" style="color:#880000">{{ attrib.file }}</a>
```

or

```
<a target='_blank' :href="attrib.link" style="color:#880000">{{ attrib.file }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
v-bind:href='attrib.link'
```

or

```
:href='attrib.link'
```